# видео плеер ie < 9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, видео

Нужен пример html видео плеера для ie < 9. И стоит ли в 2018 поддерживать ie < 9?

Comment: Ваша ЦА пользуется IE9 ? Да - делайте поддержку. Нет - не делайте.

Comment: @Kromster дело вовсе не в этом. Моя ЦА рандомная. Я не уверен, что все сидят с ie11 или более современных браузеров.

Comment: Если есть возможность, то соберите статистику, например за месяц, сколько человек сидит и с какого браузера. Если у вас уже установлен google-analytics, то это можно посмотреть в нем.